# unable to view the output screen in eclipse mars

Tags: javascript, eclipse, sapui5

I installed eclipse mars on my mac, with sapui5 plugin. But, it is not showing the output screen, while I'm trying to run it on my localhost. Can anybody tell me, why is this happening??

this appears when i run it as ->webapp preview

Comment: mars is not supported, you need Kepler or Luna.

Comment: yeah! thank you so much :D luna worked for me

Comment: Eclipse Mars is now supported. Check https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5 for the latest tools.

Comment: I still see an issue starting the web app preview.
It looks like the proxy is not working.

Comment: Are there any updates? My installation of Eclipse Mars (with latest updates also from SAPUI5 tools) is unable to load the WebApp preview. I see an endless waiting symbol from Eclipse if I start it. Any idea where to find more informations?